# Why JavaScript's Date object is invalid in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, firefox, jquery-plugins

I have date in a div which looks like "30-Apr-2013" and I want to convert it to: 30 Tuesday
APR | 2013

I have write some code to make this conversion for me. Its working fine in Chrome but some how its not working in Firefox and in firebug console it says: Date {Invalid Date} and shows output looks like NaN undefined undefined | NaN. My code looks is below or [you can also see this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5XG5/21/):

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.bcDateModify = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = this;
            var srcDate= $(obj).html();            
            srcDate = srcDate.replace(/\s+/g, '');

            objDate = new Date(srcDate);
             console.log(objDate);
            var newDate = objDate.getDate();
            var newDay = objDate.getDay();
            var newMonth = objDate.getMonth();
            var newYear = objDate.getFullYear();

            var weekday=new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
            var monthNames=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

            var myhtml ='<div class="date"><span>'+newDate+'</span></div><div class="month-day"><h3>'+weekday[newDay]+'</h3><span>'+monthNames[newMonth]+' | '+newYear+'</span></div>';
            $(obj).html(myhtml);
        });

    };

}( jQuery ));

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.date-obj').bcDateModify();
});
```

Comment: in firebug console it says: Date {Invalid Date}. and shows output looks like NaN undefined undefined | NaN

Comment: Add `console.log(srcDate);` before `objDate = new Date(srcDate);` and write what did it log

Comment: @KamilT it shows: 21-Jul-2013, btw you can see this in jsfiddle I have provided.

Comment: Just get rid of the dashes. `new Date('30 Apr 2013');`

Comment: [`Date(dateString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date): String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the parse method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps). - [`Date.parse(dateString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) "A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot construct a date the way you are (at least in Firefox you can't), for example passing in the string "22-Jul-2013".

I changed this line

```
objDate = new Date(srcDate);
```

to

```
var dateSplit = srcDate.split("-");            
objDate = new Date(dateSplit[1] + " " + dateSplit[0] + ", " + dateSplit[2]);
```

to ensure the date was constructed correctly.

See the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s5XG5/24/).

Answer (score 4):

Just found this [item](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=671312) regarding the usage of dates with hyphens in FF. Seems like none of the FF versions support that format.

One possible alternate is to replace the `-` with a  prior to constructing the date.

```
srcDate = srcDate.replace(/-/g, ' ');
```

This solution works cross browser and has been tested in Firefox v19, Chrome v24 and Safari v5.1.7 (on Windows).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s5XG5/60/)

Comment: poor firefox developers :(

Answer (score 1):

I know this likely isn't the best answer but I have found these types of things to be really tricky cross browser. This small library has saved me a ton of time.

http://momentjs.com/

```
moment("30-Apr-2013", "DD-MMM-YYYY").format("DD dddd MMM | YYYY");
```

Honestly I feel like JavaScript should have this stuff built in like PHP or other languages.